# How to load image icon from package using java

Tags: java, swing, package, embedded-resource, imageicon

I want use code

```
URL iconURL = getClass().getResource("/some/package/favicon.png");
// iconURL is null when not found
ImageIcon icon = new ImageIcon(iconURL);
frame.setIconImage(icon.getImage());
```

for load image from package and set as a icon for my `JFrame`.

The image is in package `com.app.image` and name is `logo.png`.

When I build URL:

```
URL iconURL = getClass().getResource("/com/app/image/logo.png");
```

I am getting `null` in `iconURL`. Where is a problem?

Comment: is the `com` folder at the root of a folder of the classpath ?

Comment: Yes. `com` is root package.

Comment: Is the image actually contained within the Jar file or class path?  If you have a Jar file, unzip it and check it's contents and make sure the image exists (where you think it should be)

Comment: @MadProgrammer I check jar archive, but image is not included in jar.

Comment: @triotrou Well, there's you problem, you can't load a resource which doesn't exists. How to fix it requires more context then you've made available - in particular, how you are creating the Jar